# Select multiple tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I want to write an extension, which can allow users to use their mouses to select multiple tabs in Chrome (the select tabs will be highlighted), just like some multiple-tab handler extensions for Firefox, I have searched but didn't find any useful information, so I am wondering if there is a way to do it, or it's technically possible to build such an extension given Chrome's design?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to Program an extension because Google already beat you to it.  See the answer that is already posted.  He beat me to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently I'm using Google Chrome v20.0.1132.47 m
I can say this is already possible on that version.

All you need to do is to hold-down the CTRL key on the keyboard and then single-left click on each desired tab to multi-select them.

In addition, once they're selected, you can drag-drop them off the main window to create an independent session with those tabs on the new session. Really useful on dual monitors.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, is there any way for an extension to detect the selected multiple tabs?

Comment: [This seems Windows ONLY](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78816)

Comment: nit-picky detail, you can also use the `SHIFT` key to select a range of tabs, just as you would with files in Windows Explorer / Finder

Answer (score 3):

You can use the windows get function to get all of the tabs in a specified window or instead use getAll and iterate through each window then each tab within each of those windows. You must specify the option populate:true to get the tabs array to return populated. The property highlighted should tell you if that tab is highlighted.

```
chrome.windows.get(integer windowId, {populate:true}, function (window) {
    var highlightedTabs = new Array();
    for(var index in window.tabs)
        if(window.tabs[index].highlighted)
            highlightedTabs.push(windows.tabs[index]);

    // your code here
});
```

For a full reference to the format of the tab object see below:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#types